# How to implement a left-to-right swipe in a SwiftUI list?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm building a to-do app in Swift as a practice project, and would like to make it so that when the user swipes from left to right on a task in the list, my "`completed`" boolean in the task becomes `true`. Similar how in the native Mail app, swiping right on an email marks it read.

I came across the `onDelete()` function provided by Apple that handles right to left swipes, but as far as I can tell there's no code for left to right swipes. I think that makes it ok to implement a left to right swipe, but I can't find any examples of how to do so in SwiftUI. I think this question was asked once on Stack Overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56779283/swiftui-table-custom-swipe), but the answer only pertained to deleting and moving.

Comment: You can try drag gesture, also you may play with your row’s x offset & slide a custom view in

Answer (score 2):

## iOS 15

You can define any number of actions with `.swipeActionis` modifier for either `leading`, or `trailing` side of the cell with the given view as the `label` and give them a `tint` color like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

that called gestures and for swipe gesture you can see the documentation here - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiswipegesturerecognizer

and if you don't want to make it from scratch then you can use library for it and the kind of functionality you want go for this library `SwipeCellKit` here is link https://cocoapods.org/pods/SwipeCellKit with this you can easily make the kind of functionality you want.

Comment: The user asks for a swiftUI, not UIKit